# Android Defaul Http Client

Tags: android

In my android app i have to get response from the php server. So i used DefaultHttpClient in that i have to maintain session cookies for subsequent requests for that i avoided creation of new instance for DefaultHttpClient using singleton pattern.But the problem is when i switch off and on the phone app  creates new instance for DefaultHttpClient so my session cookies get destroyed.How to maintain DefaultHttClient even when phone restarts?

Thanks.

Comment: Please, could you kindly edit your question so that it doesn't format as code block.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you save your cookie data into a persistent storage 
( like SharedPreferences / SQLite / or a cookie file ).

Here is a link to more info on [Android Storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html)

You can do this in your `onPause()` method.

Then you can get the data in your `onResume()` method. 

And of course also check for local cookies in your `onCreate()`

Answer (score 2):

I recommend using the [Android Asynchronous Http Client](http://loopj.com/android-async-http/) library, which automatically handles persistent cookie storage to android `SharedPreferences`.

See the documentation here:

http://loopj.com/android-async-http/#persistent-cookie-storage-with-persistentcookiestore